# How to wrap the images in winforms listview?

Tags: c#, winforms

[sample requirement image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqRMw.png) I need to wrap the images to next line when the horizontal space over in winform. But the images shown only vertically please suggest some way to achieve this?

```
border_listview.Location = new Point(10, 35);
border_listbox.Size=new System.Drawing.Size(123,123);
border_listview.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
// border_listview.MultiColumn = true;
// var colel=new ImageCollection();
var image1=new Bitmap(typeof(SfSpreadsheet).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Spreadsheet.Resources.FormatCellsIcons.NoneLineStyle.png"));
var image3 = new Bitmap(typeof(SfSpreadsheet).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Spreadsheet.Resources.FormatCellsIcons.LineStyle2.png"));
var image2 = new Bitmap(typeof(SfSpreadsheet).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Spreadsheet.Resources.FormatCellsIcons.LineStyle1.png"));
var image4 = new Bitmap(typeof(SfSpreadsheet).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Spreadsheet.Resources.FormatCellsIcons.LineStyle3.png"));
var image5 = new Bitmap(typeof(SfSpreadsheet).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Spreadsheet.Resources.FormatCellsIcons.LineStyle4.png"));
var image6 = new Bitmap(typeof(SfSpreadsheet).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Spreadsheet.Resources.FormatCellsIcons.LineStyle5.png"));
var image7 = new Bitmap(typeof(SfSpreadsheet).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Spreadsheet.Resources.FormatCellsIcons.LineStyle6.png"));
var image8 = new Bitmap(typeof(SfSpreadsheet).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Spreadsheet.Resources.FormatCellsIcons.LineStyle7.png"));
var image9 = new Bitmap(typeof(SfSpreadsheet).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Spreadsheet.Resources.FormatCellsIcons.LineStyle8.png"));
var image10 = new Bitmap(typeof(SfSpreadsheet).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Spreadsheet.Resources.FormatCellsIcons.LineStyle9.png"));
var image11 = new Bitmap(typeof(SfSpreadsheet).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Syncfusion.Windows.Forms.Spreadsheet.Resources.FormatCellsIcons.LineStyle10.png"));
var list = new ImageList();
list.ImageSize = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 10);
list.Images.AddRange(new Image[] { image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, image7, image8, image9, image10, image11 });
border_listview.SmallImageList = list;           
border_listview.View = View.SmallIcon;
border_listview.Scrollable = false;           

for (int j = 0; j < list.Images.Count; j++)
{
    var item = new ListViewItem();
    item.ImageIndex = j;
    border_listview.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `ListView` with these settings:

- Set `View` to Tile
- Use `LargeImageList`
- Set the `TileSize` based on your image list `ImageSize`
- Set the `Alignment` to Left, so items will fill a column first, then goes to next column.
- Set `Scrollable` to false, to hide probable scrollbars.
- Add some items and set ImageKey/ImageIndex for items.
- Use suitable size for your ListView

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks  it's working as expected but one more requirement is selection of items does not shown any border and which makes background color as blue but its not clearly identify the selected item